# How to clip a section of webpage with all styles (similar to what clipboard.com did)

Tags: html, css, dom, reverse-engineering, clipping

I've been a user of clipboard.com a clipping service which is about to be shut down, one of the killer features was that you can clip a section of the webpage with all its contents and styling, it was like cropping an image, but instead of static content you could crop webpage content and then later you would be able to open the clipped content with all its styling, images, text, elements like buttons and forms, even flash was in place. And I want to create something similar, but I can't come up with an exact algorithm on how to do that.

From what I understand you can achieve something like that by inlining all styles for each element inside a DOM subtree and looks like this is what guys form clipboard.com did, here is an example of the clip:

[a web clip http://monosnap.com/image/CIiUXkvHM3hKFxWkDbJQRtgtW.png](http://monosnap.com/image/CIiUXkvHM3hKFxWkDbJQRtgtW.png)

And this is its code in inspector [clip code in inspector http://monosnap.com/image/PatIGWGY0ZjfSCdFnfwNkBGzy.png](http://monosnap.com/image/PatIGWGY0ZjfSCdFnfwNkBGzy.png)

But I'm afraid this naive approach wouldn't work, for instance if you are clipping a div which has negative margin it will effectively go of the viewport.

So the question is what would be a proper way to implement something like this?

Comment: you could install Zotero for Firefox and save complete pages offline as well as snaps of the time you saved it. Or, are you trying to create an app like that for other purposes than saving content for yourself?

Comment: Well since the Clipboard.com is going to be shut down I was thinking about creating some similar service or opensource project that would allow you to save such clips. But thanks for the Zotero I will definitely look at it